# The specified share already exists on Azure Storage File Shares

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-files

I am using "Azure Storage File Shares" to store some files from our website, but failed with error message "The specified share already exists".
I have change the file that being upload, but the error persist.
Here my code

```
        public static void Test2Upload()
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
string shareName = "myapp-dev";
        string dirName = "files";
        string fileName = "catto.jpg";

        // Path to the local file to upload
        string localFilePath = @"d:\temp\two.jpg";

        // Get a reference to a share and then create it
        ShareClient share = new ShareClient(connectionString, shareName);
        share.Create();

        // Get a reference to a directory and create it
        ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(dirName);
        directory.Create();

        // Get a reference to a file and upload it
        ShareFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient(fileName);
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
        {
            file.Create(stream.Length);
            file.UploadRange(
                new HttpRange(0, stream.Length),
                stream);
        }
    }
```

Looks like I should not create ShareClient with same name several times.
Then how to check and use it?

The most important question is, why the file still not yet uploaded (even if I rename the ShareClient object)?

Answer (score 2):

> Looks like I should not create ShareClient with same name several
> times. Then how to check and use it?

You can use [`ShareClient.CreateIfNotExists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.shareclient.createifnotexists?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-files-shares-shareclient-createifnotexists(azure-storage-files-shares-models-sharecreateoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) instead of `ShareClient.Create` method. Former will try to create a share but if a share already exists, then it won't be changed.

You can also use [`ShareClient.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.shareclient.exists?view=azure-dotnet) to check if the share exists and then create it using `ShareClient.Create` if it does not exist. This is not recommended however as it might not work if multiple users are executing that code at the same time. Furthermore, you will be making 2 network calls - first to check the existence of share and then the second to create it.

> The most important question is, why the file still not yet uploaded
> (even if I rename the ShareClient object)?

Your code for uploading the file looks ok to me. Are you getting any error in that code?

Comment: You are right.. 

But similar problem happen on ShareDirectoryClient part which formerly like this : 

            ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(dirName);
            directory.Create();

Thanks to you I could fix it like below : 

             ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(dirName);
             directory.CreateIfNotExists();

Comment: Yes, that's the correct approach. Use `directory.CreateIfNotExists`.

Answer (score 0):

We could use ShareClient.CreateIfNotExists when creating ShareClient object to avoid the problem. Like below

```
ShareClient share = new ShareClient(connectionString, shareName); 
share.CreateIfNotExists();
```

You might found Similar problem on ShareDirectoryClient.
This part purpose is to create the folder structure.
The upload will fail if the destination folder is not exist.

Error will occur if we create a folder when it already exist.
So, use method ShareDirectoryClient.CreateIfNotExists, like below

```
ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(dirName);
directory.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Here my complete code

```
public static void TestUpload()
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

            string shareName = "myapp-dev";
            string dirName = "myfiles";
            string fileName = "catto.jpg";

            string localFilePath = @"d:\temp\two.jpg"; 

            // Get a reference to a share and then create it
            
            ShareClient share = new ShareClient(connectionString, shareName);
            share.CreateIfNotExists();
             
            // Get a reference to a directory and create it
            ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(dirName);
            directory.CreateIfNotExists();
            

            // Get a reference to a file and upload it
            ShareFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient(fileName);
            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
            {
                file.Create(stream.Length);
                file.UploadRange(
                    new HttpRange(0, stream.Length),
                    stream);
            }
        }
```